# CQL: comparing two column values

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have a `TABLE` like this:

```
    id   | expected | current
   ------+----------+--------
     123 |    25    |   15
     234 |    26    |   26
     345 |    37    |   37
```

Now I want to select all `ids` where `current` is equal to `expected`. In SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE current = expected;
```

But in CQL it seems to be invalid. My `cqlsh` returns this:

```
no viable alternative at input 'current'
```

Is there a valid CQL query to achieve this ?

**Edited**
According to the CQL-Docs it should work but it doesn't... This is what the doc says:

```
<selectWhereClause> ::= <relation> ( "AND" <relation> )*
                      | <term> "IN" "(" <term> ( "," <term> )* ")"

<relation> ::= <term> <relationOperator> <term>

<relationOperator> ::= "=" | "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">="

<term> ::= "KEY"
         | <identifier>
         | <stringLiteral>
         | <integer>
         | <float>
         | <uuid>
         ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the wrong docs. I'm using CQL3 and read the docs for CQL2. 
The correct doc says:

```
<where-clause> ::= <relation> ( AND <relation> )*

<relation> ::= <identifier> <op> <term>
             | '(' <identifier> (',' <identifier>)* ')' <op> '(' <term> (',' <term>)* ')'
             | <identifier> IN '(' ( <term> ( ',' <term>)* )? ')'
             | TOKEN '(' <identifier> ( ',' <identifer>)* ')' <op> <term>
```

So it is not a valid query.